# what is the key Difference between Object declaration in python. How parenthesis makes is different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

Ex 1:

```
class foo:
    def test():
        print("test completed")
        
obj = foo()
obj.test()
```

RESULT:
TypeError: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Ex 2:

```
class foo:
    def test():
        print("test completed")
        
obj = foo
obj.test()
```

OUTPUT:-
test completed

EX 3:

```
class foo:
    def test(self):
        print("test completed")
        

obj = foo()
obj.test()
```

OUTPUT:
test completed

Comment: If your function does not depend on any particular instance's state, then it does not require `self` and therefore should be `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` as appropriate

Comment: First case: you made an instance and called the method through the instance. This calls implicitly sending a ```self``` to the method as a result you are given an error warning.

Second case: Well, you are assigned a variable ```class``` to another variable and then call through it. Because the method doesn't need a `self`` argument then it simply becomes a ```simple function```

Third case: Same as first case, but you explicitly stated an ```self``` inside the method, so it, well, works.